# Python: for loop not filtering correctly

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

This is what I want to do:
I have different list in 3 different dictionaries.

I want to add values from lists in dictionary1, to dictionary2.
However, if one of the values in dictionary1, is in dictionary3, then it will stop adding values.

The problem is:
The for loop im using to do this, dosent stop adding values, even if they exist in dictionary3.

dictionary1 is possible_moves

dictionary2 is possible_moves_within_fence

dictionary3 is fence

```
fence = {
    "right_fence": list(range(8, 65, 8)),
    "left_fence": list(range(1, 58, 8)),
    "top_fence": list(range(1, 9)),
    "bottom_fence": list(range(56, 65)),
}


# Mulige posisjoner brikken kan bevege seg
possible_moves = {
    "tower": {
        "left-down": list(range(self.place_of_brick, 65, 7)),
        "left-up": list(range(self.place_of_brick, 1, -9)),
        "right-down": list(range(self.place_of_brick, 65, 9)),
        "right-up": list(range(self.place_of_brick, 1, -7)),
    }
}

possible_moves_within_fence = {
    "left-down": list(),
    "left-up": list(),
    "right-down": list(),
    "right-up": list(),
}


for key in possible_moves["tower"].keys():

    for number in possible_moves["tower"][key]:
        possible_moves_within_fence[key].append(number)
        if number in (
            fence["top_fence"]
            or fence["bottom_fence"]
            or fence["right_fence"]
            or fence["left_fence"]
        ):
            print(number)
            break
```

Comment: Python is not English. `number in` is not distributive across the following `or` clauses.

Comment: What do you mean? As long as I use the methods in python I should be fine?

Comment: `number in (a or b or c or d)` first evaluates `(a or b or c or d)` which gives you `a` (if `a` is non-empty). It doesn't do `number in a or number in b or number in c or number in d`.